# firebase_admin generate_reset_password_link not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using pycharm as the ide. And I already have firebase initialized .But I wanted to use the generate_password_reset_link option.So I installed firebase_admin in to the project. I downloaded the json file and I think it should be saved as a static file in pycharm. However that gave me an error. so I did the following. But I keep getting the error firebase_admin has no attribute called auth , or firebase_admin has no attribute called generate_password_reset_link. Can someone please help

```
    import firebase_admin
    from firebase_admin import credentials

    cred = {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "private_key": "",
      "client_email": "",
      "client_id": "",
      "auth_uri": "",
      "token_uri": "",
      .............
   }

    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    email = request.POST.get('email')
    link = firebase_admin.auth.generate_email_verification_link(email)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the `auth` module:

```
from firebase_admin import auth
```